# Handling OnFailure method in call.enqueue in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, socket-timeout-exception

I was testing my app to handle an event of a `SocketTimeoutException` which should be handled by the `OnFailure` method in `Call.Enqueue`

NOTE: I reduce the `TimeOutEXCEPTION` timer to 10ms.

**Repository**

```
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsDataFromJson>, t: Throwable) {
            MainActivity.apiRequestError = true
            Log.d("err_msg", "MainActivty.apiRequestError value: ${MainActivity.apiRequestError}")
         
            Log.d("err_msg", "msg: ${t.message}")
            MainActivity.errorMessage = t.localizedMessage as String
            
        }
```

When the code is ran, the log produces the correct responses, I reassigned the `apiRequestError` variable **Companion object** to `true` so I can handle the response in the `MainActivity`

So the way I implemented to deal with `OnsocketTimeoutException` is to reassign the variables `apiRequestError` and `errorMessage` which is located in the `MainActivity Companion Object.`

```
2023-05-15 17:58:33.292 3638-3638/com.example.newstest D/err_msg: MainActivty.apiRequestError value: true
2023-05-15 17:09:34.267 3372-3372/com.example.newstest D/err_msg: msg: failed to connect to newsapi.org/104.26.13.149 (port 443) from /10.0.2.16 (port 44172) after 10ms
```

This is how I call the requests in the `MainActivity Oncreate method`, upon running the app, the Log below would display `False` even though it is supposed to be `True`.

```
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("MainActivity","Answer: $apiRequestError" )
        requestNews(GENERAL, generalNews, "us")
            requestNews(TECHNOLOGY, TechNews, "us")
            requestNews(HEALTH, healthNews, "us")
            requestNews(SPORTS, SportsNews, "us")
            requestNews(ENTERTAINMENT, EntertainmentNews, "us")
            requestNews(SCIENCE, ScienceNews, "us")
            requestNews(BUSINESS, BusinessNews, "us")
        }
```

The Log statement is

```
2023-05-15 17:09:34.062 3372-3372/com.example.newstest D/MainActivity: Answer: false
```

This is the way I handle each request in the `MainActivity`.

```
    suspend private fun requestNews(newsCategory: String, newsData: MutableList<Article>,country:String) {
    viewModel.getNews(category = newsCategory, Country = country)?.observe(this) {
        newsData.addAll(it)
        totalRequestCount += 1

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {


    if (ScienceNews.isNotEmpty() && BusinessNews.isNotEmpty() && EntertainmentNews.isNotEmpty() && generalNews.isNotEmpty() && healthNews.isNotEmpty() && SportsNews.isNotEmpty() && TechNews.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.d("MainActivity","Answer $OnSocketTimeOut 1" )
        if (apiRequestError == false) {
            Log.d("MainActivity","Answer $OnSocketTimeOut 2" )
            ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
            FragmentContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else if (apiRequestError == true) {
            Log.d("MainActivity","Answer $OnSocketTimeOut 3" )
            ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
            FragmentContainer.visibility = View.GONE
            val showError: TextView = findViewById(R.id.display_error)
            showError.text = errorMessage
            showError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    } else if (apiRequestError == true) {
        Log.d("MainActivity","Answer $OnSocketTimeOut 4" )
        ProgresBar.visibility = View.GONE
        FragmentContainer.visibility = View.GONE
        val showError: TextView = findViewById(R.id.display_error)
        showError.text = errorMessage
        showError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the Companion object variable `apiRequestError` is giving the wrong value, my app is in a perpetual state of loading whenever a `SocketTimeoutException` occurs.

[image]

Is there a way to convey the correct value from the `Repository` to the `MainActivity`?